# Web Push Panel Post URL Redirection

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, push-notification, web-push

I do not know much about coding, but recently I got a self-hosted web-push panel made for my website by a developer, he also gave a plugin for my WordPress website. The admin panel works fine, there is something wrong with it, maybe he didn't fix it on purpose

Like when I send a notification of a post from my WordPress website, the notification goes but when the subscriber clicks on that post, it gets redirected to a different URL when I checked the files of the panel, I found a file called link.php

There is a code in that file in which that Redirect URL is set as if I set that URL to google.com, then after clicking on my post, the user landed on google.com and not on my post and the developer did the same With many things, I was given a script like unlimited subscribers, but the notification goes to only 10k people.

Now I am not having any contact with that developer so how can I fix this redirection problem please give any suggestion

link.php code

```
<?php

const BASE_PATH = __DIR__;
require_once BASE_PATH.'/system/init.php';

$linkId = (isset($_GET['linkId']) && !empty(trim($_GET['linkId'])))? SQLSecure(base64_decode($_GET['linkId'])) : '0';

$linkQuery = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `id`='{$linkId}'");
if($linkQuery->num_rows > 0){
    $LinkData = $linkQuery->fetch_assoc();
    $DB->query("UPDATE `links` SET `clicks`=`clicks`+1 WHERE `id` = '{$LinkData['id']}'");
    redirect($LinkData['full_link']);
}
redirect('https://google.com');

?>
```

the other file code, mentioned in the link.php file system/init.php

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly',1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies',1);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'Strict');
session_start();

require_once BASE_PATH.'/config.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/core/database.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/core/functions.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/core/app-start.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

This redirect function first finds the previously generated ID in the database. If the ID is found, the link will be taken and redirected to. If not, I will switch back to google. In case your ID does not exist in the database, it should be transferred to google. It seems that the code has an error in the function of inserting ID and URL into the database.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).